# POST HTML FORM verificaton doesn't work with Django

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-templates, django-urls

I am currently learning Django,I connected my register FORM with my views.py, and wrote a little backend code, the problem, is that it links successfully with my .html file, and the POST elements are registering, but as I try to make a verification, (`if POST_element < 10`), it does nothing.

Edit: The Post elements are recognised by my backend, I test it out with a print(username) statement and it works fine.

Here is a part of my HTML Register FORM:

```html
<div class="limiter">
        <div class="container-login100" style="background:black;">
            <div class="wrap-login100">
                <form action="{% url 'register' %}" method="POST" class="login100-form validate-form">
                    {% csrf_token %}
                    <span class="login100-form-logo">
                        <i class="zmdi zmdi-landscape"></i>
                    </span>
                    <span class="login100-form-title p-b-34 p-t-27">
                        Register
                    </span>

                    <div class="wrap-input100 validate-input" data-validate = "Enter username">
                        <input class="input100" type="text" name="username" placeholder="Username">
                        <span class="focus-input100" data-placeholder="&#xf207;"></span>
                    </div>
```

Here is a part of my views.py that manages register:

```py
def register(request):
    if request.method=="POST":
        username = request.POST["username"]
        password = request.POST["pass"]
        password_confirm = request.POST["pass-confirm"]
        email = request.POST["mail"]
    
        if len(username) < 7:
            messages.error(request,"Username must be more than 10 char.") #Don't get any error

        else:
            messages.success(request,"Success")

    return render(request, 'users/register.html')
```

Here is my urls.py:

```py
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.register, name='register'),
    path('login/', views.login, name='login')
]
```

Comment: Your html code is hardcoded, `csrf_token` will work automatically if you create form through `Form API`, in this scenario you can create hidden field, and verify it.

Comment: Do you have code in your HTML file responsible for displaying django messages? Is debugger stopping at messages.error(request, "Username....")?

Comment: It does find my POST informations, I tested it out with print(username), I think the problem is the validation

Comment: @Sdev Refer [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/forms/api/).

Comment: @SunderamDubey, if I want to create a Form with Form API, I can't use my own styling?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An Excerpt from the [`django-doc`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpResponseRedirect) about `POST` request.

> You should always return an HttpResponseRedirect after successfully dealing with POST data. This tip isn’t specific to Django; it’s good web development practice in general.

You haven't return any response in `POST` request, and the `messages` framework whether any messages consists of `error,success,etc`. will send messages to next redirected page, so that's why you are not able to see the message, and your condition is working.

check the below code:

Html code:

```
<div class="limiter">
    <div class="container-login100" style="background:black;">
        <div class="wrap-login100">
            <form class="login100-form validate-form"  method='POST' action="{% url 'users:register' %}" >
                {% csrf_token %}
                <span class="login100-form-logo">
                    <i class="zmdi zmdi-landscape"></i>
                </span>

                <span class="login100-form-title p-b-34 p-t-27">
                    Register
                </span>

                <div class="wrap-input100 validate-input" data-validate = "Enter username">
                    <input class="input100" type="text" name="username" placeholder="Username" required>
                    <span class="focus-input100" data-placeholder="&#xf207;"></span>
                </div>

                <div class="wrap-input100 validate-input" data-validate="Enter password">
                    <input class="input100" type="password" name="pass" placeholder="Password" required>
                    <span class="focus-input100" data-placeholder="&#xf191;"></span>
                </div>

                <div class="wrap-input100 validate-input" data-validate="Confirm password">
                    <input class="input100" type="password" name="pass-confirm" placeholder="Confirm Password" required>
                    <span class="focus-input100" data-placeholder="&#xf191;"></span>
                </div>

                <div class="wrap-input100 validate-input" data-validate="Enter Email">
                    <input class="input100" type="email" name="mail" placeholder="E-Mail" required>
                    <span class="focus-input100" data-placeholder="&#xf191;"></span>
                </div>

                <div class="container-login100-form-btn">
                    <button class="login100-form-btn">
                        Register
                    </button>
                </div>

                <div class="text-center p-t-90">
                    <a class="txt1" href="login">
                        Already registered?
                    </a>
                </div>

            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Set following style at the top of page in `<style>` tag, i.e. inline style:

```
<style>
    .green{
        color:green;
        font-size:1.3rem;
    }
    .red{
        color:red;
        font-size:1.3rem;
    }
</style>
```

urls.py

```
app_name='users'
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.register, name='register'),
    path('login/', views.login, name='login')
]
```

> `Note:` Giving `app_name` is a good practice,works like `template namespacing` while giving urls.

views.py

```
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.contrib import messages
from django.urls import reverse


def register(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        username = request.POST["username"]
        password = request.POST["pass"]
        password_confirm = request.POST["pass-confirm"]
        email = request.POST["mail"]

        # Here everying exist.
        print("UserName : ", username)
        print('Email : ', email)
        print('Password : ', password)
        print('Password Confirm : ', password_confirm)

        if len(username) < 7:
            # Here error exist.
            print('Username must be more than 10 char.')
            messages.error(
                request, "Username must be more than 10 char.", 'red')
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('users:register'))

        else:
            messages.success(request, "Success! form submitted.", 'green')
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('users:register'))

    return render(request, 'users/register.html')
```

> `Note:` You can also do password `hashing` through `make_password` which is `from django.contrib.auth.hashers import make_password`.